# How to execute MySQL query with range of years in one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a table that is using year ranges for some of the data I need to be able to
select a record by a year that falls between those ranges.

```
| id | Make      | Model      | Year        |
|----------------|------------|------------ |
| 1  | Chevrolet | Camaro     | 2008        |
| 2  | Chevrolet | Camaro     | 2009 - 2014 |
| 3  | Dodge     | Avenger    | 2010 - 2015 |
| 4  | Dodge     | Challenger | 2008 - 2016 |   
| 5  | Ford      | Escape     | 2013        |
| 6  | Ford      | Mustang    | 2004 - 2012 |
| 7  | Ford      | Mustang    | 2015        |
```

For example, I want to be able to ***Select all vehicles with a year of 2012***.

This should return: **2**, **3**, **4** and **6** given the example table below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to determine the ranges.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE (LEFT(Year,4) <= '2012' AND RIGHT(Year,4) >= '2012')
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  Make        Model       Year
2   Chevrolet   Camaro      2009 - 2014
3   Dodge       Avenger     2010 - 2015
4   Dodge       Challenger  2008 - 2016
6   Ford        Mustang     2004 - 2012
```

SQL Fiddle:

Comment: Isn't the first condition detrimental? You would be accepting some weird data like `a2012445.^`, and your 2nd condition already catches `2010-2012`, `2012-2013` as well as `2012`.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard absolutely correct! Its actually redundant as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   t WHERE  LEFT(Year,4) <= '2012' AND RIGHT(Year,4) >= '2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:
Of course you have to check the table if all columns with year-ranges are in the same context, else this won't work.

```
select *
from table
where (Year = '2012' and substring( Year, 6, 1) <> '-')
 or   (  substring(Year, 6, 1) = '-'
     and substring(Year, 1, 4) <= '2012')
     and substring(Year, 8, 4) >= '2012'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Year` column is guaranteed to always have one or two years, then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `my_table`
WHERE
    CAST(LEFT(`Year`, 4) AS SIGNED) <= 2012
    AND CAST(RIGHT(`Year`, 4) AS SIGNED) >= 2012
```

This would catch a column with `2012` or with `2000 - 2015` etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use get start and end year using `LEFT/RIGHT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, CAST(LEFT(Year, 4) AS INT) AS s, CAST(RIGHT(Year,4) AS INT) AS e
  FROM tab
) AS sub
WHERE sub.s <= 2012 AND sub.e  >= 2012;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398758)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I would first try to restructure the database so you have two separate fields for the maximum and minimum years.  However, sometimes we are stuck with someone else's bad design decisions.  In this case, `substring_index()` with silent conversion is useful:

```
select t.*
from t
where 2012 >= (year + 0) and -- does silent conversion on the first value in the field
      2012 <= (substring_index(year, ' - ', -1) + 0);
```

If you input the year as a string, you don't need the silent conversion:

```
select t.*
from t
where '2012' >= substring_index(year, ' - ', 1) and
      '2012' <= substring_index(year, ' - ', -1);
```